# Which .NET assembly contains the definition for FormRegionMessageClass and FormRegionName?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, outlook, vsto

I am trying to create a form region for Microsoft Outlook 2013 using Visual Studio Tools for Office. The assembly will not load because the following error is thrown:

```
The type or namespace name 'FormRegionMessageClassAttribute' could not be found (are you   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

The type or namespace name 'FormRegionNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

As far as I can see I have the correct reference to the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook assembly in my project, but still doesn't help.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this issue? The code is auto-generated, so I find it strange that this is happening.

Comment: "Are you missing a using directive"?

Comment: I think you need the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll" reference instead of just "Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook"

Comment: Thanks guys,here are my using statements:-using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook;-  And here are the offending lines of code, I have modified them with what should be the correct namespaces:[Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Contact)]
        [Outlook.FormRegionName("FSSOutlookAddIn.FormRegion1")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.outlook.formregionmessageclassattribute.aspx).

And its usage is:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class FormRegionMessageClassAttribute : Attribute
```

(This is from the MSDN documentation linked above).